# How to mock AuthenticationManager authenticate method using Spring Security and Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-security, mockito, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to use Mockito to test whether when the user hits the login api, it will respond with a JWT token. However, I keep getting the `Bad Credentials` error which comes from the authenticationManager.authenticate() method inside Spring Security. I'm now trying to mock this method, but I keep getting a variety of different errors and not sure if my approach is correct. This is my latest implementation, which now fails with `You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing` as it's not liking how I'm using the mocks.

```
@WebMvcTest(value = UserCommandController.class, includeFilters = {
    // to include JwtUtil in spring context
    @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = JwtUtil.class)})
class UserCommandControllerTest {

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserCommandControllerTest.class);

@MockBean
private UserCommandService userCommandService;

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@MockBean
private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl;

@MockBean
private JwtUtil jwtUtil;

@Autowired
private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

@Autowired
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

private static UserDetails dummy;
private static String jwtToken;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    dummy = new User("user@email.com", "123456", new ArrayList<>());
    jwtToken = jwtUtil.generateToken(dummy);
}


@Test
void testLoginReturnsJwt() throws Exception {

    AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest = new AuthenticationRequest("user@email.com", "123456");
    AuthenticationResponse authenticationResponse = new AuthenticationResponse("anyjwt");

    String jsonRequest = asJsonString(authenticationRequest);
    String jsonResponse = asJsonString(authenticationResponse);

    RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .post("/api/adverts/user/login")
            .content(jsonRequest)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    Authentication authentication = mock(Authentication.class);
    authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
    when(authentication.isAuthenticated()).thenReturn(true);

    when(authenticationManager.authenticate(any())).thenReturn(authentication); // Failing here

    when(jwtUtil.generateToken(dummy)).thenReturn("124");
    when(userDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(eq("user@email.com"))).thenReturn(dummy);

    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(request)
            .andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful())
            .andExpect(content().json(jsonResponse, true))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.jwt").value(isNotNull()))
            .andReturn();
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/login", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> loginUser(@Valid @RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {

    try {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authenticationRequest.getUsername(), authenticationRequest.getPassword()));
    } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
        throw new Exception("incorrect username or password", e);
    }

    UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());

    String jwt = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(new AuthenticationResponse(jwt));
}
```

Thank you.

PS: Here is my repo and where AuthenticationManager is set: https://github.com/francislainy/adverts-backend/blob/dev_jwt/src/main/java/com/example/adverts/MyWebSecurity.java#L30

Comment: A shot in the dark: your AuthenticationManager is not a mock. Try annotating it with `@MockBean` instead of `@Autowired`.

Comment: Thank you. I'd tried that before but I'm afraid I get the same error.

Comment: How do you set AutenticationManager in your controller?

Comment: Here is my repo: https://github.com/francislainy/adverts-backend/blob/dev_jwt/src/test/java/com/example/adverts/controller/user/UserCommandControllerTest.java#L333

Comment: AuthenticationManager is here: https://github.com/francislainy/adverts-backend/blob/dev_jwt/src/main/java/com/example/adverts/MyWebSecurity.java#L30

Comment: Post the full exception stacktrace as well please.

Comment: In the source code I can see that you put `@MockBean` on `authentication`, not on `authenticationManager` - not what I meant. Try removing `@Autowired` from `authenticationManager` field and annotate it with `@MockBean` instead. There's no way you'll get a `You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing` in this case.

Comment: Yes, I'd done that too but not on the version pushed. I've just done it again now. I have both authentication and authenticationManager as @mockBean and I get the same error.

Comment: ```java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:10) at com.example.adverts.controller.user.UserCommandControllerTest.testLoginReturnsJwt(UserCommandControllerTest.java:359)
 at Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:

-> at com.example.adverts.controller.user.UserCommandControllerTest.testLoginReturnsJwt(UserCommandControllerTest.java:359)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `AuthenticationManager` to be a mock and in your code it's not (`@Autowired` injects a "real" instance). You can mock beans using [MockBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html) annotation:

```
@MockBean
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

Now you can mock `authenticationManager` all you want.

Another problem with your code is that you are misusing the `ArgumentMatchers.isNotNull()` matcher in your assertions causing an exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:

-> at com.example.adverts.controller.user.UserCommandControllerTest.testLoginReturnsJwt(UserCommandControllerTest.java:356)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(any());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
    when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

[ArgumentMatchers](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#argument_matchers) provides matchers to be used in method call stubbing and verification. You should use [org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers#notNullValue()](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/CoreMatchers.html#notNullValue()) instead.

With these fixes your test passes all in green.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. Yes, using                `.andExpect(jsonPath("$.jwt").value(is(notNullValue())))` and the @MockBean fixed the problem. And it was not needed to mock the authenticate method so I removed those when related lines. Cheers.

Comment: A have a similar issue to your question. I wanted to know if the your GrantedAuthorities in the Mocked AuthenticationManager was empty @FrancislainyCampos